# How to get the value of specific object in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have a result array which looks like this:

```
Array
  (
    [formdata] => [{"id":"1"},{"name":"name"}]
  )
```

Now I want to get the value of `id` but I can't get it right.
The code I've done so far is:

```
      foreach ($text as $key => $file) {
        print_r($file['id']); //<--- it shoud print 1
      }
```

Comment: Can you give us the thing that you are trying to parse? This looks a lot like JSON so it may be an issue with how it is structured or how you are parsing it

Comment: The value inside `formdata` seems like a JSON object. If it is so, you can use `json_decode`to access your data easily.

Comment: Try to include more detailed data and code. Context is everything when it comes to understanding.

Comment: The way you use array and objects in conjunction is so wrong in many levels.

Answer (score 0):

Simple Example to what Babak commented:

```
$var['formdata'] = '[{"id":"1"},{"name":"name"}]';

$var2 = json_decode($var['formdata']);

foreach($var2 as $item) {

    echo $item->id;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$var2 = json_decode($var['formdata'], true);
echo $var2[0]['id'];
```